# Java EE - WebLogic sever - Deployment Error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I downloaded Oracle with Java EE.

I uploaded my project from uni then ran my SessionBean and I obtained this error message...

```
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -javaagent:toplink/jlib/toplink-essentials-agent.jar -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Ddomain.home=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.60\DEFAUL~1 -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Djrockit.optfile=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.60\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1 -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.60\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.60\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.60\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.60\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -Dwsm.repository.path=C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.60\DEFAUL~1\oracle\store\gmds  -DUSE_JAAS=false -Djps.policystore.hybrid.mode=false -Djps.combiner.optimize.lazyeval=true -Djps.combiner.optimize=true -Djps.auth=ACC -Doracle.core.ojdl.logging.usercontextprovider=oracle.core.ojdl.logging.impl.UserContextImpl -Doracle.wc.openusage.clustername=localhost -Doracle.wc.openusage.collectorport=31314 -Doracle.wc.openusage.timeout=30 -Doracle.wc.openusage.unicast=true -Doracle.wc.openusage.enabled=false -Doracle.webcenter.tagging.scopeTags=false -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dwc.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper  -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1033\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : toplink/jlib/toplink-essentials-agent.jar
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I'm quite new to Java EE so anything would be of help, the whole project works in the Java EE in uni.

Comment: Are classpaths OK? IT could not find the toplink-essentials-agent.jar Do a search for it and see if it is included in any project structure/other settings.

Comment: I searched my whole computer for "toplink-essentials-agent.jar" and it cannot seem to find it :S. 

This is my system CLASSPATH variable ".;C:\Users\Daniel\jogl-1.1.1-windows-i586\lib\jogl.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\jogl-1.1.1-windows-i586\lib\gluegen-rt.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\j3d\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\j3d\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\j3d\lib\ext\vecmath.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\New Folder\compute.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip"

Comment: look on the University computer for the toplink-essentials-agent.jar file.  Also, can you provide the Manifest.mf file from your EJB?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm quite new to Java EE so anything would be of help, the whole project works in the Java EE in uni.

I'm surprised to find the option `-javaagent:toplink/jlib/toplink-essentials-agent.jar` in the startup line. It looks like you're using JDeveloper, I wonder if JDeveloper is doing that.

If you don't use JPA in your code, a quick way to work around the issue would be to just remove this option from the startup script.

This won't solve the real problem (which is that the toplink jar is missing or not found) but well, if you don't use JPA... Moreover, I don't do JDeveloper :)

---

> I am using JDeveloper :). I'm doing persistence in uni, I think I might need it. Thanks :)

Well, WebLogic is a Java EE container and  does provide a JPA implementation (Oracle WebLogic 10.3 ships with EclipseLink 1.0 if I'm not wrong).

I still believe that the Toplink stuff is added by some settings of JDeveloper, you don't need it unless you **really** want to use TopLink instead of EclipseLink. But that would be the complicated way.

Comment: I am using JDeveloper :). I'm doing persistence in uni, I think I might need it. Thanks :)